# Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 dock Gen 2 not working correctly

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, dock, hdmi

I have an M2 MacBook Pro with an issue regarding a docking station. I'll write some specs first so you know what I'm working with.

Laptop:

- MacBook Pro M2, 16 inch
- macOS Sonoma 14.0

Dock:

- Lenovo Thinkpad Gen2 Thunderbolt 3 dock
- Cable is a Thunderbolt 3 cable

Plugged in the dock:

- Philips 4K monitor 60 Hz - plugged with HDMI
- Iiyama 2K 165 Hz or just 60 Hz idc about the hz - plugged with HDMI
- mouse
- keyboard

When I plug in my Thunderbolt cable, I only get the 2K monitor with a bust up bottom bar, like like horizontal black lines. Second of all my 4K monitor doesn't even pop up in the display settings **or** turn on. When I unplug my 4K monitor HDMI from my dock and plug it in my Mac it works well, but the 2K monitor still has the black lines.

My mouse and keyboard seem to work fine, but when I play around for a minute, I seem to be unable to click buttons on my screen (for example, the "About this Mac" top navigation buttons).

When I remove the dock everything works fine again, when I plug it back in same thing happens.

I came from a Windows 11 laptop where the dock works perfectly.

Comment: It's a known issue as we can see here : https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkStation-Workstations/Thinkpad-Hybrid-USB-C-with-USB-A-Dock-compatibility-with-Macbooks/m-p/5134764

I just found a video of @BsianTech "Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Gen 2 Dock with Macbook Pro Experience" showing a workaround with an HMDI to USB-C plugged into the front USB-C port.

I also experienced it just yesterday but didn't even try to find a solution lol.

Comment: I think i have a bit of a different problem no? My 2k screen does connect but with the black lines at the bottom, the second monitor doesn't get connected at all... Or do you mean that the thinkpad has issues with macbook all together?